# The Chow ring of a blow-up along a badly embedded subscheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, blow-ups, chern-classes, chow-groups

Let $X$ be a variety and $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$ be a regularly embedded closed subvariety, and write $\tilde X$ for $Bl_Y X$ the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$. Let $A^*(X)$ refer to the Fulton-Macpherson operational Chow groups of $X$.

If one assumes $i^*:A^*(X)\rightarrow A^*(Y)$ is surjective, there is a result of Keel (1992, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., the appendix) that describes $A^*(\tilde X)$ in terms of $A^*(X)$ and the Chern classes $c_i(N_Y X)$ of the normal bundle to $Y$ in $X$. In more detail, $A^*(\tilde X)$ is isomorphic to $A^*(X)[T]/(P(T),(T\cdot ker(i^*)))$, where $P(T)\in A^*(X)[T]$ is any polynomial with constant term $[Y]$ and whose restriction to $A^*(Y)$ is the Chern polynomial of the normal bundle $N_Y X$.

If $Y$ is not regularly embedded, then instead of a normal bundle there is only the normal cone $C_Y X$. Cones do not have Chern classes, but they have Segre classes, and so I am wondering:

Has anyone developed a description of $A^*(\tilde X)$ in terms of $A^*(X)$ and the Segre classes $s_i(C_Y X)$? Even special cases (e.g. toric varieties) are welcome.

Comment: A bit confused about which variety is embedded in which: if $Y\hookrightarrow X$ the normal bundle of $X$ in $Y$ looks weird.

Comment: I am following the conventions of Fulton's Intersection Theory. Y is embedded in X, $N_Y X$ is the normal bundle to $Y$ in $X$.

Comment: What confuses me is "the Chern classes $c_i(N_YX)$ of the normal bundle of $X$ in $Y$," but on a second reading I guess that "in $Y$" part refers to the Chern class, nor the normal bundle, right?

Comment: Corrected, thanks. Actually I will try to add a bit more since I think some clarification is necessary.

Comment: Non regular blow ups are difficult to control. If $Y \subset X$ is not a regular embedding then the blow up morphism may not even induce a pull-back on the Chow groups. The simplest example to consider is the blow up of the vertex of the cone $X$: $xy = z^2$, which is its resolution. Furthermore $A^*(X)$ will not embed into $A^*(\widetilde{X})$: in the quadric cone case the Chow groups of the cone have torsion but the resolution has torsion-free Chow groups.

Comment: Also you need to explain the notation: typically $A^*$ is not used for (Fulton's) Chow groups of singular varieties, because they don't form a ring, don't have a correct functoriality and overall fail to be a cohomology theory. As I understand Chow-cohomology are still not constructed (see Srinivas ICM talk).

Comment: Sorry, some of my comment above apply only to the usual Chow (homology) groups. I looked at Keel's paper and he seems to be actually using Chow cohomology, I suppose these are the so-called Fulton's operational Chow groups. In any case this needs to be explained in the question.

Comment: I do indeed mean operational Chow or Chow cohomology, which have pullbacks along arbitrary morphisms. These are isomorphic to the usual Chow groups with intersection product when X is smooth, and as far as I know there is no other competitor for the term "Chow ring" when X is singular. I will edit this in for clarity.

Comment: Would it answer the question negatively if we find an example of a singular variety $X$ with a blow up $\tilde{X}$ such that the pull-back $\pi^*: A^*(X) \to A^*(\tilde{X})$ is not injective?

Comment: @A.S. There are definitely competitors for „Chow rings of general schemes“. For instance cdh-hypercohomology of the Suslin-Voevodsky complex in degree n and weight 2n. By construction, arbitrary blow-ups induce Mayer-Vietoris like long exact sequences in this context.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder That would be interesting. Something that makes me think this is unlikely is that there is an exact sequence due to S. Kimura (Fractional intersection and bivariant theory, Communications in Algebra, 1992) which says that if $\pi:\tilde X \rightarrow X$ is an envelope (proper, and for every subvariety $V$ in $X$ there is $\tilde V$ in $\tilde X$ that maps to $V$ surjectively and birationally) then $A^*(X)\rightarrow A^*(\tilde X)$ is injective. I don't know if all blow-ups are envelopes in this sense or not though.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski Is it known whether this theory should admit a map to operational Chow?

Comment: @A.S. No, it should not. This construction of Suslin-Voevodsky is cohomological by nature (but this fits with $A^*(X)$ when $X$ is not singular), while (operational) Chow groups are related with Borel-Moore homologies (which fits with $A_*(X)$ for all $X$'s). Bloch's higher Chow groups will be related to (operational) Chow groups though, and will also have long exact sequences associated to arbitrary blow ups (at least in char. 0, or in char. p>0 if you invert p).

Comment: There is also a bivariant construction of Friedlander and Voevodsky which encodes both the cohomological version and the Borel-Moore homology version at once (and fits perfectly in Voevodsky's theory of mixed motives).